# How do I validate an array of JSON objects in a json object?

Tags: json, laravel, validation

I'm sending have an array of JSON objects that I'm POSTing to the DB with other data:

```
{
   "emotions":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "intensity":67,
         "new_intensity":67
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "intensity":67,
         "new_intensity":67
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "intensity":64,
         "new_intensity":64
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "intensity":64,
         "new_intensity":64
      },
      {
         "id":5,
         "intensity":64,
         "new_intensity":64
      }
   ],
   "situation":"An event",
   
}
```

What I want to do is validate both the `situation` and `emotions[{},{}]` json array:

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $this->validate($request, [
      'situation' => 'required',
   ]); 
   $data = ['data' => $request->input('emotions')];
   $this->validate($data, [
      'data.*.id' => 'digits:2|between:1,70',
      'data.*.intensity' => 'digits:3|between:1,100',
      'data.*.new_intensity' => 'digits:3|between:1,100'
   ]);
}
```

**Error**

> Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given

I'd like to be able to combine the two validating methods, but I have no idea how to do that as well?

[Here is the answer I got my first try from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46222928/11386185)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array validators](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-arrays). Something like below code may help you achieve this

```php
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
      'data.*.id' => 'digits:2|between:1,70',
      'data.*.intensity' => 'digits:3|between:1,100',
      'data.*.new_intensity' => 'digits:3|between:1,100'
   ])
```

You can check whether it fails and do your desired action

```
if($validator->fails()){
    // Do something
}
```